# why i cannot send android intent from within new thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

```
  private void Foo() {

    //  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("driveUri", file.getAlternateLink());
            startActivityForResult(i, SAVE);
       }
    });
    t.start();
  }
```

I get this error:
`The constructor Intent(new Runnable(){}, Class<TodoDetailActivity>) is undefined`

I have tried to change to explicit declaration, but it didn't help

`android.content.Intent i = new android.content.Intent.Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);`

though I know there is such a signature from past use.

Answer (score 7):

This line

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);
```

Is inside the Anonymous Class `Runnable`.

Change it to

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TodoDetailActivity.class);
```

Comment: is it better to use asuncTsak for that purpose ? or doesn't matter?

Comment: For calling a new activity, no need to put that in a different thread or `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change 
`Intent i = new Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);` in 
`Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TodoDetailActivity.class);` if you are in a Fragment, or
by 
`Intent i = new Intent(yourActualActivity.this, TodoDetailActivity.class);` if you are in an Activity

Answer (score 0):

You are using Itennt() inside the Thread, so `this` means thread's object, which is wrong for Intent's syntax.

You should modify your code as follows,

```
private void Foo() 
{
    //  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TodoDetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("driveUri", file.getAlternateLink());
            startActivityForResult(i, SAVE);
       }
    });
    t.start();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent need context (of some activity of application), but in thread **this** (in new Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);) passes the context of you thread, which is not an activity.

so just `getApplicationContext()` or context of activity form which thread is started like `MainActivity.this`